# Web Page Development with IntelliJ - Auto Preview?

Tags: intellij-idea

If I want to develop a web page in IntelliJ, is there a web to automatically preview the results in a browser, for example, so I don't always have to manually force a browser refresh?

```
<html>
<body>
hello world.
I'd like to see the browser refresh...
as I type
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Web Facet`
Please note usually it's a bit annoying, as it's refreshing everytime you type or pause (this is what you want, but that means some delays will occur if your page is complex)

More details here:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-web-application-support.html